# ActivityOptions returns NoClassDefFoundError on some android versions

Tags: java, android

I developed an android app with ACRA for crash reporting. I got some crashes when trying to make an animation for startActivity(). I know that ActivityOptions is not supported before API 16, so I added a check for the android version when the app starts.

This is a snippet of Wheel.java:

```
public static void ini()
{
    sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        api16 =  true;
    else
        api16 =  false;
}

public static boolean isAPI16()
{
    return api16;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static Bundle getNextAnimation(Context context)
{
    Bundle animation = null;
    if(isAr())
        animation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(context, R.anim.rtl_enter, R.anim.rtl_exit).toBundle();
    else
        animation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(context, R.anim.ltr_enter, R.anim.ltr_exit).toBundle();

    return animation;
}
```

And this is how I used it all over my app:

```
if(Wheel.isAPI16())
    startActivity(i);
else
    startActivity(i, Wheel.getNextAnimation(getApplicationContext()));
```

That code gave me those crashes:

```
Android Version   Phone                            Error

4.0.3             samsung samsung GT-N7000         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.ActivityOptions : at com.nasseralsalmi.wheel.Wheel.getNextAnimation(Wheel.java:103)
4.0.4             HTC htc_ara HTC One X            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.ActivityOptions : at com.nasseralsalmi.wheel.Wheel.getNextAnimation(Wheel.java:101)
```

Then I tried to fix it like this:

```
api16 = false;
try
{
    Bundle animation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(context, R.anim.rtl_enter, R.anim.rtl_exit).toBundle();
}
catch (Exception e) // NoClassDefFoundError
{
    api16 = true;
}
```

Unfortunately:

```
Android Version   Phone                            Error
4.0.4             samsung google Galaxy Nexus      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.ActivityOptions : at com.nasseralsalmi.wheel.Wheel.ini(Wheel.java:50)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [ActivityOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html) is not defined in all versions.

The class was added in API level 16. You can either include that into your project or develop something instead it for old versions.

EDIT: ActivityOptions.jar

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IRemoteCallback;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Helper class for building an options Bundle that can be used with
 * {@link android.content.Context#startActivity(android.content.Intent, android.os.Bundle)
 * Context.startActivity(Intent, Bundle)} and related methods.
 */
public class ActivityOptions {
    /**
     * The package name that created the options.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final String KEY_PACKAGE_NAME = "android:packageName";

    /**
     * Type of animation that arguments specify.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final String KEY_ANIM_TYPE = "android:animType";

    /**
     * Custom enter animation resource ID.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final String KEY_ANIM_ENTER_RES_ID = "android:animEnterRes";

    /**
     * Custom exit animation resource ID.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final String KEY_ANIM_EXIT_RES_ID = "android:animExitRes";

    /**
     * Bitmap for thumbnail animation.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final String KEY_ANIM_THUMBNAIL = "android:animThumbnail";

    /**
     * Start X position of thumbnail animation.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final String KEY_ANIM_START_X = "android:animStartX";

    /**
     * Start Y position of thumbnail animation.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final String KEY_ANIM_START_Y = "android:animStartY";

    /**
     * Initial width of the animation.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final String KEY_ANIM_START_WIDTH = "android:animStartWidth";

    /**
     * Initial height of the animation.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final String KEY_ANIM_START_HEIGHT = "android:animStartHeight";

    /**
     * Callback for when animation is started.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final String KEY_ANIM_START_LISTENER = "android:animStartListener";

    /** @hide */
    public static final int ANIM_NONE = 0;
    /** @hide */
    public static final int ANIM_CUSTOM = 1;
    /** @hide */
    public static final int ANIM_SCALE_UP = 2;
    /** @hide */
    public static final int ANIM_THUMBNAIL_SCALE_UP = 3;
    /** @hide */
    public static final int ANIM_THUMBNAIL_SCALE_DOWN = 4;

    private String mPackageName;
    private int mAnimationType = ANIM_NONE;
    private int mCustomEnterResId;
    private int mCustomExitResId;
    private Bitmap mThumbnail;
    private int mStartX;
    private int mStartY;
    private int mStartWidth;
    private int mStartHeight;
    private IRemoteCallback mAnimationStartedListener;

    /**
     * Create an ActivityOptions specifying a custom animation to run when
     * the activity is displayed.
     *
     * @param context Who is defining this.  This is the application that the
     * animation resources will be loaded from.
     * @param enterResId A resource ID of the animation resource to use for
     * the incoming activity.  Use 0 for no animation.
     * @param exitResId A resource ID of the animation resource to use for
     * the outgoing activity.  Use 0 for no animation.
     * @return Returns a new ActivityOptions object that you can use to
     * supply these options as the options Bundle when starting an activity.
     */
    public static ActivityOptions makeCustomAnimation(Context context,
            int enterResId, int exitResId) {
        return makeCustomAnimation(context, enterResId, exitResId, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Create an ActivityOptions specifying a custom animation to run when
     * the activity is displayed.
     *
     * @param context Who is defining this.  This is the application that the
     * animation resources will be loaded from.
     * @param enterResId A resource ID of the animation resource to use for
     * the incoming activity.  Use 0 for no animation.
     * @param exitResId A resource ID of the animation resource to use for
     * the outgoing activity.  Use 0 for no animation.
     * @param handler If <var>listener</var> is non-null this must be a valid
     * Handler on which to dispatch the callback; otherwise it should be null.
     * @param listener Optional OnAnimationStartedListener to find out when the
     * requested animation has started running.  If for some reason the animation
     * is not executed, the callback will happen immediately.
     * @return Returns a new ActivityOptions object that you can use to
     * supply these options as the options Bundle when starting an activity.
     * @hide
     */
    public static ActivityOptions makeCustomAnimation(Context context,
            int enterResId, int exitResId, Handler handler, OnAnimationStartedListener listener) {
        ActivityOptions opts = new ActivityOptions();
        opts.mPackageName = context.getPackageName();
        opts.mAnimationType = ANIM_CUSTOM;
        opts.mCustomEnterResId = enterResId;
        opts.mCustomExitResId = exitResId;
        opts.setListener(handler, listener);
        return opts;
    }

    private void setListener(Handler handler, OnAnimationStartedListener listener) {
        if (listener != null) {
            final Handler h = handler;
            final OnAnimationStartedListener finalListener = listener;
            mAnimationStartedListener = new IRemoteCallback.Stub() {
                @Override public void sendResult(Bundle data) throws RemoteException {
                    h.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override public void run() {
                            finalListener.onAnimationStarted();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback for use with {@link ActivityOptions#makeThumbnailScaleUpAnimation}
     * to find out when the given animation has started running.
     * @hide
     */
    public interface OnAnimationStartedListener {
        void onAnimationStarted();
    }

    /**
     * Create an ActivityOptions specifying an animation where the new
     * activity is scaled from a small originating area of the screen to
     * its final full representation.
     *
     * <p>If the Intent this is being used with has not set its
     * {@link android.content.Intent#setSourceBounds Intent.setSourceBounds},
     * those bounds will be filled in for you based on the initial
     * bounds passed in here.
     *
     * @param source The View that the new activity is animating from.  This
     * defines the coordinate space for <var>startX</var> and <var>startY</var>.
     * @param startX The x starting location of the new activity, relative to <var>source</var>.
     * @param startY The y starting location of the activity, relative to <var>source</var>.
     * @param startWidth The initial width of the new activity.
     * @param startHeight The initial height of the new activity.
     * @return Returns a new ActivityOptions object that you can use to
     * supply these options as the options Bundle when starting an activity.
     */
    public static ActivityOptions makeScaleUpAnimation(View source,
            int startX, int startY, int startWidth, int startHeight) {
        ActivityOptions opts = new ActivityOptions();
        opts.mPackageName = source.getContext().getPackageName();
        opts.mAnimationType = ANIM_SCALE_UP;
        int[] pts = new int[2];
        source.getLocationOnScreen(pts);
        opts.mStartX = pts[0] + startX;
        opts.mStartY = pts[1] + startY;
        opts.mStartWidth = startWidth;
        opts.mStartHeight = startHeight;
        return opts;
    }

    /**
     * Create an ActivityOptions specifying an animation where a thumbnail
     * is scaled from a given position to the new activity window that is
     * being started.
     *
     * <p>If the Intent this is being used with has not set its
     * {@link android.content.Intent#setSourceBounds Intent.setSourceBounds},
     * those bounds will be filled in for you based on the initial
     * thumbnail location and size provided here.
     *
     * @param source The View that this thumbnail is animating from.  This
     * defines the coordinate space for <var>startX</var> and <var>startY</var>.
     * @param thumbnail The bitmap that will be shown as the initial thumbnail
     * of the animation.
     * @param startX The x starting location of the bitmap, relative to <var>source</var>.
     * @param startY The y starting location of the bitmap, relative to <var>source</var>.
     * @return Returns a new ActivityOptions object that you can use to
     * supply these options as the options Bundle when starting an activity.
     */
    public static ActivityOptions makeThumbnailScaleUpAnimation(View source,
            Bitmap thumbnail, int startX, int startY) {
        return makeThumbnailScaleUpAnimation(source, thumbnail, startX, startY, null);
    }

    /**
     * Create an ActivityOptions specifying an animation where a thumbnail
     * is scaled from a given position to the new activity window that is
     * being started.
     *
     * @param source The View that this thumbnail is animating from.  This
     * defines the coordinate space for <var>startX</var> and <var>startY</var>.
     * @param thumbnail The bitmap that will be shown as the initial thumbnail
     * of the animation.
     * @param startX The x starting location of the bitmap, relative to <var>source</var>.
     * @param startY The y starting location of the bitmap, relative to <var>source</var>.
     * @param listener Optional OnAnimationStartedListener to find out when the
     * requested animation has started running.  If for some reason the animation
     * is not executed, the callback will happen immediately.
     * @return Returns a new ActivityOptions object that you can use to
     * supply these options as the options Bundle when starting an activity.
     * @hide
     */
    public static ActivityOptions makeThumbnailScaleUpAnimation(View source,
            Bitmap thumbnail, int startX, int startY, OnAnimationStartedListener listener) {
        return makeThumbnailAnimation(source, thumbnail, startX, startY, listener, true);
    }

    /**
     * Create an ActivityOptions specifying an animation where an activity window
     * is scaled from a given position to a thumbnail at a specified location.
     *
     * @param source The View that this thumbnail is animating to.  This
     * defines the coordinate space for <var>startX</var> and <var>startY</var>.
     * @param thumbnail The bitmap that will be shown as the final thumbnail
     * of the animation.
     * @param startX The x end location of the bitmap, relative to <var>source</var>.
     * @param startY The y end location of the bitmap, relative to <var>source</var>.
     * @param listener Optional OnAnimationStartedListener to find out when the
     * requested animation has started running.  If for some reason the animation
     * is not executed, the callback will happen immediately.
     * @return Returns a new ActivityOptions object that you can use to
     * supply these options as the options Bundle when starting an activity.
     * @hide
     */
    public static ActivityOptions makeThumbnailScaleDownAnimation(View source,
            Bitmap thumbnail, int startX, int startY, OnAnimationStartedListener listener) {
        return makeThumbnailAnimation(source, thumbnail, startX, startY, listener, false);
    }

    private static ActivityOptions makeThumbnailAnimation(View source,
            Bitmap thumbnail, int startX, int startY, OnAnimationStartedListener listener,
            boolean scaleUp) {
        ActivityOptions opts = new ActivityOptions();
        opts.mPackageName = source.getContext().getPackageName();
        opts.mAnimationType = scaleUp ? ANIM_THUMBNAIL_SCALE_UP : ANIM_THUMBNAIL_SCALE_DOWN;
        opts.mThumbnail = thumbnail;
        int[] pts = new int[2];
        source.getLocationOnScreen(pts);
        opts.mStartX = pts[0] + startX;
        opts.mStartY = pts[1] + startY;
        opts.setListener(source.getHandler(), listener);
        return opts;
    }

    private ActivityOptions() {
    }

    /** @hide */
    public ActivityOptions(Bundle opts) {
        mPackageName = opts.getString(KEY_PACKAGE_NAME);
        mAnimationType = opts.getInt(KEY_ANIM_TYPE);
        if (mAnimationType == ANIM_CUSTOM) {
            mCustomEnterResId = opts.getInt(KEY_ANIM_ENTER_RES_ID, 0);
            mCustomExitResId = opts.getInt(KEY_ANIM_EXIT_RES_ID, 0);
            mAnimationStartedListener = IRemoteCallback.Stub.asInterface(
                    opts.getIBinder(KEY_ANIM_START_LISTENER));
        } else if (mAnimationType == ANIM_SCALE_UP) {
            mStartX = opts.getInt(KEY_ANIM_START_X, 0);
            mStartY = opts.getInt(KEY_ANIM_START_Y, 0);
            mStartWidth = opts.getInt(KEY_ANIM_START_WIDTH, 0);
            mStartHeight = opts.getInt(KEY_ANIM_START_HEIGHT, 0);
        } else if (mAnimationType == ANIM_THUMBNAIL_SCALE_UP ||
                mAnimationType == ANIM_THUMBNAIL_SCALE_DOWN) {
            mThumbnail = (Bitmap)opts.getParcelable(KEY_ANIM_THUMBNAIL);
            mStartX = opts.getInt(KEY_ANIM_START_X, 0);
            mStartY = opts.getInt(KEY_ANIM_START_Y, 0);
            mAnimationStartedListener = IRemoteCallback.Stub.asInterface(
                    opts.getIBinder(KEY_ANIM_START_LISTENER));
        }
    }

    /** @hide */
    public String getPackageName() {
        return mPackageName;
    }

    /** @hide */
    public int getAnimationType() {
        return mAnimationType;
    }

    /** @hide */
    public int getCustomEnterResId() {
        return mCustomEnterResId;
    }

    /** @hide */
    public int getCustomExitResId() {
        return mCustomExitResId;
    }

    /** @hide */
    public Bitmap getThumbnail() {
        return mThumbnail;
    }

    /** @hide */
    public int getStartX() {
        return mStartX;
    }

    /** @hide */
    public int getStartY() {
        return mStartY;
    }

    /** @hide */
    public int getStartWidth() {
        return mStartWidth;
    }

    /** @hide */
    public int getStartHeight() {
        return mStartHeight;
    }

    /** @hide */
    public IRemoteCallback getOnAnimationStartListener() {
        return mAnimationStartedListener;
    }

    /** @hide */
    public void abort() {
        if (mAnimationStartedListener != null) {
            try {
                mAnimationStartedListener.sendResult(null);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    /** @hide */
    public static void abort(Bundle options) {
        if (options != null) {
            (new ActivityOptions(options)).abort();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the current values in this ActivityOptions from those supplied
     * in <var>otherOptions</var>.  Any values
     * defined in <var>otherOptions</var> replace those in the base options.
     */
    public void update(ActivityOptions otherOptions) {
        if (otherOptions.mPackageName != null) {
            mPackageName = otherOptions.mPackageName;
        }
        switch (otherOptions.mAnimationType) {
            case ANIM_CUSTOM:
                mAnimationType = otherOptions.mAnimationType;
                mCustomEnterResId = otherOptions.mCustomEnterResId;
                mCustomExitResId = otherOptions.mCustomExitResId;
                mThumbnail = null;
                if (otherOptions.mAnimationStartedListener != null) {
                    try {
                        otherOptions.mAnimationStartedListener.sendResult(null);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    }
                }
                mAnimationStartedListener = otherOptions.mAnimationStartedListener;
                break;
            case ANIM_SCALE_UP:
                mAnimationType = otherOptions.mAnimationType;
                mStartX = otherOptions.mStartX;
                mStartY = otherOptions.mStartY;
                mStartWidth = otherOptions.mStartWidth;
                mStartHeight = otherOptions.mStartHeight;
                if (otherOptions.mAnimationStartedListener != null) {
                    try {
                        otherOptions.mAnimationStartedListener.sendResult(null);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    }
                }
                mAnimationStartedListener = null;
                break;
            case ANIM_THUMBNAIL_SCALE_UP:
            case ANIM_THUMBNAIL_SCALE_DOWN:
                mAnimationType = otherOptions.mAnimationType;
                mThumbnail = otherOptions.mThumbnail;
                mStartX = otherOptions.mStartX;
                mStartY = otherOptions.mStartY;
                if (otherOptions.mAnimationStartedListener != null) {
                    try {
                        otherOptions.mAnimationStartedListener.sendResult(null);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    }
                }
                mAnimationStartedListener = otherOptions.mAnimationStartedListener;
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the created options as a Bundle, which can be passed to
     * {@link android.content.Context#startActivity(android.content.Intent, android.os.Bundle)
     * Context.startActivity(Intent, Bundle)} and related methods.
     * Note that the returned Bundle is still owned by the ActivityOptions
     * object; you must not modify it, but can supply it to the startActivity
     * methods that take an options Bundle.
     */
    public Bundle toBundle() {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        if (mPackageName != null) {
            b.putString(KEY_PACKAGE_NAME, mPackageName);
        }
        switch (mAnimationType) {
            case ANIM_CUSTOM:
                b.putInt(KEY_ANIM_TYPE, mAnimationType);
                b.putInt(KEY_ANIM_ENTER_RES_ID, mCustomEnterResId);
                b.putInt(KEY_ANIM_EXIT_RES_ID, mCustomExitResId);
                b.putIBinder(KEY_ANIM_START_LISTENER, mAnimationStartedListener
                        != null ? mAnimationStartedListener.asBinder() : null);
                break;
            case ANIM_SCALE_UP:
                b.putInt(KEY_ANIM_TYPE, mAnimationType);
                b.putInt(KEY_ANIM_START_X, mStartX);
                b.putInt(KEY_ANIM_START_Y, mStartY);
                b.putInt(KEY_ANIM_START_WIDTH, mStartWidth);
                b.putInt(KEY_ANIM_START_HEIGHT, mStartHeight);
                break;
            case ANIM_THUMBNAIL_SCALE_UP:
            case ANIM_THUMBNAIL_SCALE_DOWN:
                b.putInt(KEY_ANIM_TYPE, mAnimationType);
                b.putParcelable(KEY_ANIM_THUMBNAIL, mThumbnail);
                b.putInt(KEY_ANIM_START_X, mStartX);
                b.putInt(KEY_ANIM_START_Y, mStartY);
                b.putIBinder(KEY_ANIM_START_LISTENER, mAnimationStartedListener
                        != null ? mAnimationStartedListener.asBinder() : null);
                break;
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get it ActivityOptions is not included in APIs below 16. That's why I added a check for the device API: if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN). The thing is that Android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 are API 15. So the activity should start with no animation (ActivityOptions not used) instead it called ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation() and caused an exception !!!

Comment: Why don't you download it and add to your project? Or, why don't you implement it as an empty class, having some empty methods to fail gracefully?

Comment: That doesn't explain the issue. But it will solve the problem.

Comment: From where should I download it ??

Comment: Please, look here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/app/ActivityOptions.java

Comment: I have edited my answer to add the source-code of ActivityControl class.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a problem with a Static Class that was keeping my Global variables and sometimes i was receiving crash reports about this class (ClassDefNotFoundError). I decides to move my Global variables into my Application class that this problem solved forever.